# How to install Jasper on Raspberry Pi 3 (Model B)?

Tags: pi-3, image, partition

Sorry ahead of time, I'm new to Raspberry Pi's.

I am trying to install Jasper by using its guide (https://jasperproject.github.io/documentation/installation/), but I cannot seem to figure it out.

In the guide, it says to image the SD card with their .img file, so I did and I put the card on the Pi and it didn't start. So I thought it was something like maybe I'm suppose to wipe the SD card, install NOOBS, put it on the Pi, install Raspbian then image the Jasper file to one of the partitions that was created upon starting up the Pi with NOOBS, but that just made the Pi not boot up when I put the SD card in with a partition imaged.

I don't know whether I am supposed to image a particular partition or what I should do.

Any help is greatly appreciated, cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to install Jasper manually. Here is a short summary (for more details see [Method 3: Manual Installation](https://jasperproject.github.io/documentation/installation/#manual-installation)
)
:

- Install and configure Raspbian as usual
- Clone Jasper Github repo and install/configure Jasper
- Install and configure dependencies for TTS engine

But as Milliways said this link is obsolete and Jasper seems not under active development anymore (last commit was from January 2017)

You may want to use an alternative like [Kalliope](https://kalliope-project.github.io/). It aims to be a personal assistant with a similar concept like Alexa Skills.

Comment: Thanks for the summary and recommendation. I'll look into Kalliope.

Answer (score 2):

The link is to a hopelessly obsolete Wheezy distribution, which won’t work on a current model Pi.

Any OS released before the Pi is unlikely to work.
The Pi3 was announced 29 Feb 2016 and only supported on Jessie.

Answer (score 0):

took a couple of edits, and a bit of work, but I now have it installed.  I'll let you know if it works or not later.  For the edits you can check the mail list at rssc.org.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/116964)